# Need a sheet formula to do a 5 min countdown if reference cell AO10 is 5 minutes away from =now()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Need a sheet formula to do a 5 min countdown if reference cell AO10 is 5 minutes away from =now(). Remain blank if it's beyond 5 minutes and =now() is past the date and time in cell AO10.

The date and time format is DDD MMM DD YYYY HH:MM (24 hour format)

Tried different formulas I found online (can't remember most of them), tried to play with it a bit, and also AI but none worked.

I'm no spreadsheet wiz. Need help. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Counter

```
=LET(targ,AO10, mins,5, 
   dif,targ-NOW(), dur,(mins/60)/24,
   IFERROR(
     1/(1/((dif>0)*(dif<=dur)*dif))))
```

- Formula will run every time the spreadsheet is edited.
- custom number format for the result can be set to **`"M:SS"`**

Also see this question: [Creating a script that runs every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763305/creating-a-script-that-runs-every-second)